# How to wrap rectangle around circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, shapes

I'm trying to recreate the below picture for a poster. But I am not sure how to do this. 
I know how to wrap text around a circle, but I also want the rectangle to wrap around the circle, but I am not able to do this.

Perhaps, another way on how this is done, is by making one large rectangle and then 'cutting' this into smaller pieces, but I am also not sure on how this is done.

I am trying to do this in inDesign but perhaps I should do this in Illustrator?

Can someone please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**InDesign** (Animation shows InDesign CS6 panels)

It is not necessary to cut or otherwise alter the standard simple geometric shapes. *Unless* you want those yellow glows as well. In that case, you need to cut the shapes as Danielillo suggests.

Without the glows, all that is required is a proper stacking order and proper fills/strokes.

- Stack white rectangular shapes on a color background rectangle.
- Place the circle shape in the center and fill it with white and give it a thick stroke matching the background color.
- Place text frames in proper locations
- Add a text wrap to the circle - The text frames will then wrap to the circle

[image]

Because of how the glows interact around the center circle, to create them properly the shapes need to be cut so they don't "glow" into the background color. With cut shapes, you would still add the text wrap to the circle as in the above animation, but the inner glows would not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In InDesign is possible to use the **Pathfinder Panel** as in Illustrator

[image: pathfinder]

- Make the background shapes and two circles: the text container circle
  and the gap circle
- Select the background shapes and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Win to make a **Compound Shape**
- Select this compound shape together with the big gap circle and from the **Pathfinder Panel** click **Subtract**